# Contribute to WordPress Plugin using SVN

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins, open-source, git-svn

I want to contribute to a WordPress plugin, I asked plugin support, and they only have the WordPress default SVN repo.

I don't how to send pull requests using SVN,

Can anybody assist me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[I ended up asking a similar question on the users@subversion.apache.org mailing list.](https://lists.apache.org/thread/ctjofqdrqzgjbhxrqs989b3fhz3op2b6) Here’s what I learned:

It doesn’t look like there’s a direct equivalent of GitHub-style pull requests for Subversion. Here’s the normal process for proposing changes to Subversion repos:

1. Choose a repo that you want to contribute to. In this example, I’m going to contribute to https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/.
2. If you don’t already have a one, then make a working copy of the project’s trunk:

   ```sh
   svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/ subversion-trunk
   ```

   Notice how I added **trunk/** to the end of the URL. If you don’t do that, then it will include more than just the trunk in your working copy which will make things take longer.
3. `cd` into your working copy:

   ```sh
   cd subversion-trunk
   ```
4. If you already had a working copy and it’s been sitting around for a while, then update it:

   ```sh
   svn update
   ```
5. Make the changes that you want to contribute.
6. Generate a patch:

   ```sh
   svn diff -x-p > ../my-changes.patch
   ```
7. Email the patch to the project’s mailing list. When writing your email, be sure to…

   - …put “[PATCH]” the in the subject of your email.
   - …write a log message for your patch. Put it between triple square brackets like this:

     ```plaintext
     Hi,

     Here’s my log message:

     [[[
     * README:
       Add some nonsense as an example
     ]]]

     I hope that I did a good job at writing that log message.
     ```
   - …either copy and paste the patch file into the body of the email or attach it to the email. Personally, I recommend attaching it because many email clients mess up the formatting of patches when you put them in to body of your message.

As far as I know, that’s the normal process for contributing code within [the Apache Software Foundation](https://apache.org/). The process might be different elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

If you use GitHub, you can implement with GitHub action for deploying to WordPress SVN

See the documentation:

https://github.com/10up/action-wordpress-plugin-deploy

```
 - name: WordPress Plugin Deploy
      uses: 10up/action-wordpress-plugin-deploy@stable
      env:
        SVN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SVN_PASSWORD }}
        SVN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SVN_USERNAME }}
        SLUG: my-super-cool-plugin # optional, remove if GitHub repo name matches SVN slug, including capitalization
```

Comment: @HeyMehedi If answer is correct, you can vote and accept the answer

Comment: Thanks, Valerii Vasyliev,
Maybe "Plugin Deploy Action" is for those who have committer access to the plugin, isn't it? The plugin is not mine, and I don't have the committer access. is there any way?

**sorry that was the wrong comment**

Comment: @HeyMehedi Of course, for this action need access to svn on wordpress.org. In your github repository need set up secrets SVN_PASSWORD, SVN_USERNAME

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to contribute without having the committer access of svn?

Comment: @HeyMehedi Can you open the door in a stranger's house without a key?

Comment: Sorry, no......

Comment: Valerii Vasyliev, I think that you have misunderstood HeyMehedi’s question. What did you think that he was asking?